# How to prevent self-closing <tags/> in XML?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I modify XML file using the `Transformer` class and transform method. It correctly modify my parameters but changed XML style (write XML attributes in different way):

Original:

```
<a struct="b"></a>
<c></c>
```

After edit:

```
<a struct="b"/>
<c/>
```

I know that I can set properties: `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.KEY,value),` but I did not find proper settings.

Can anyone help the transformer not change the write format?

```
XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()
Source src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new 
StringReader(xmlArray[i])));
<<modify xml>>
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();          
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
           StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(src, new StreamResult(buffer));
            xmlArray[i] = buffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those forms are semantically equivalent.  No conforming XML parser will care, and neither should you.

Comment: Maybe it is true but I wouldn't like modify this.

Comment: "Maybe" its true?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe: It is of course entirely true, regardless of anyone's likes or dislikes.